# Netherlands residence - return visa for Brazilian citizen

Tags: air-travel, netherlands

I am a Brazilian citizen, currently residing in the Netherlands, and my residence permit is scheduled to expire soon.

I (in this case my employer) have already applied for a new residence permit.

However, I intend to travel outside the EU around the date of my visa expiry, which opens the possibility that I will not have yet received my residence permit when I leave the country.

Given that, as a Brazilian citizen, I can stay for 3 months in the Netherlands without a visa, must I apply for a Return Visa in order to enter the Netherlands when I get back from my trip (around a week after the old document expiry)?

Comment: A problem might be that on a visa-free stay, you cannot work and you have to convince the immigration authorities that you plan to leave again. Both could be difficult with your history.

Comment: I don't plan to leave. I live here and just want to pick up my new residence permit.

Comment: That's just my point. You would be a resident on a tourist visa.

Comment: If anyone ends up here, in here it explains that if you have no visa requirement to enter the Netherlands, you do not need a return visa. https://ind.nl/en/Pages/Appointment-for-a-return-visa.aspx